# HSQLDB equivalent to "Use <databasename>;"

Tags: jdbc, database-schema, hsqldb

I am trying to figure out how you tell HSQLDB which database to work with.  With MySQL for example, I'd enter:

```
  use testbd;
```

Toe work only tables from "testdb".

When you start a HSQLDB session with the "[HSQL Database Manager](http://hsqldb.org/doc/util-guide/dbm-chapt.html)" shows all the schemas (databases).  It then allows you to select a database to '*use*'.

How can I just specify the database Testdb so my queries can look like:

```
  SELECT * FROM NAMES;
```

instead of long-winded:

```
  SELECT * FROM TESTDB.NAMES;
```

command?   Also is there a different method to do that programaticly via JDBC, ODBC or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *database* is selected as part of the JDBC URL. You can not change that at runtime without creating a new connection.

But you are mixing up terminology anyway

```
SELECT * FROM TESTDB.NAMES
```

selects from a **schema** called `testdb` **not** from a "database" (MySQL doesn't distinguish between a database and a schema, that's probably why you mixed up the terminology as well)

The SQL standard defines two namespace levels: catalog and schema.

A fully qualified name is `database_name.schema_name.object_name`. You can only leave out parts from the beginning. So `foo.bar` references a table `bar` in the schema `foo`. As HSQLDB does not support more than one catalog per database (or actually: the current database *is* the "catalog") you can always leave out the catalog name when referencing a table.

See the manual for details: 
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_names_references

To avoid having to specify the table's schema, you can change the *current* schema using the `set schema` statement:

```
SET SCHEMA testdb;
```

This is also documented in the manual:
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#N10BBF

Comment: MySQL isn't the only database in the world, I just figured others would be familiar enough to get the gist of the question.  My bad for loose language.

Comment: In JDBC you would use [`setSchema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSchema-java.lang.String-) to switch between schema and [`setCatalog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-) to switch between databases (if supported by the driver/database).